What is the difference between the STT and MTT in USB 2.0 interface?
What is pins difference of USB2.0 device in case of STT and MTT?
A "Single-TT" hub (also called "per hub") device has one TT in the controller, and a "Multi-TT" hub (also called "per port") device has one TT for each port in the controller
is the MTT hub device is compatibility for STT device in USB 2.0 ?

In SST hub, if you have several FS devices attached to downstream facing ports (DFP), each FS device will be served one-by-one. The FS bandwidth (10-12Mbit/s) will be shared between all attached devices, even if the upstream port operates at high 480Mbps rate.
With the MTT hub, each downstream FS device will get full FS bandwidth.
There is no difference in pins on device nor on DFP side, it is just about capability of hub's Transaction Translator to remember/buffer data streams from/to individual FS devices.
